# EF Core The seed entity for entity type 'ClientType' cannot be added because a non-zero value is required for property 'Id'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I am using EF Core 2.2.6 and I am trying to seed some enum values into a table. I have the following:

```
    var clientTypes = new List<ClientType>();
    foreach (var enumVal in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ClientTypeEnum)))
        clientTypes.Add(new ClientType { Id = (int)enumVal, Name = enumVal.ToString() });
    modelBuilder.Entity<ClientType>().HasData(clientTypes); 



public class ClientType
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Icon { get; set; }
}

public enum ClientTypeEnum
{
    NewClient = 1,
    Archived = 2,
}
```

When I run `Add-Migration` I get the following error:

`EF Core The seed entity for entity type 'ClientType' cannot be added because a non-zero value is required for property 'Id'. Consider providing a negative value to avoid collisions with non-seed data.`

Why is this happening?

Comment: The `Id` property is DataBaseGenerated, but you are trying to insert a value: `clientTypes.Add(new ClientType { Id = (int)enumVal`. Despite that can be executed in some DB in a direct query, it is not, when you are using Entity Framework Core. Id must be setted to `0` in order to automatically generate the correct value. Also you can remove `autoincrement` from de DB

Comment: Sorry. Accidentally copied pasted Id Identity attribute. Changed it to ```DatabaseGeneratedOption.None``` and works now